# Updating value of Enum

Tags: swift

I have an enum that I use to populate a collection View and data changes based on API call and when this call is made, I want to change the `subTitle value` here is what I have currently

```
enum BalanceType: String, CaseIterable {

    case ledger

    case available
        
    var backgroundImage: UIImage {
        switch self {
        case .ledger:
            return R.image.walletBgNonWithdrawable()!
        case .available:
            return R.image.walletBgWithdrawable()!
        }
    }
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .ledger:
            return "Contribution Ledger Balance"
        case .available:
            return "My Available Balance"
        }
    }

    var subTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case .ledger:
            return Util.df2so(LedgerBalanceModel.currentWallet()?.totalLedgerBalance ?? 0)
        case .available:
            return Util.df2so((LedgerBalanceModel.currentWallet()?.totalLedgerBalance ?? 0) - (LedgerBalanceModel.currentWallet()?.totalMinBalance ?? 0))
        }
    }
}
```

my call that should update the value is

```
func showLedgerBal(_ data: LedgerBalanceModel) {

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: What's the question, though... i.e. what is the difficulty that you're facing? Your question is phrased as "can you write this code for me", but you don't give any details of what `reloadData` is supposed to be doing

Comment: No @NewDev. My question is is it possible to modify the `subTitle` in the enum `BalanceType`. The reload data is the function where the `subTitle` would be updated

Comment: `subTitle` is a computed getter property based on, what appears to be, external source. So, what do you mean by "modify the `subTitle`"? It will be "modified" based on data in `LedgerBalanceModel....`

Comment: Yes. The function `showLedgerBal` passes an updated `LedgerBalanceModel` that is why I have the `collectionView.reloadData()` there @NewDev

Comment: Sure. But it's still unclear to me what you mean by "modify". An Enum cannot have stored properties (except as associated values), and in any case, you're using a static function of `LedgerBalanceModel` to compute `subTotal`. An Enum is a type whose values are one of its cases. So, if `collectionView` is/has some kind of array of `BalanceType`, then all it has are values like `[.ledger, .ledger, .available]`. You can change any of them to another case, but that's it. Perhaps you need to redesign this; this is rather unusual to use external source for a computed property of an enum

Comment: Okay, got your point. Thank you @NewDev